# Почему набирает популярность C++ в академической среде?

Tags: обсуждение

Почему на форумах становятся всё популярнее учебные вопросы по этому языку?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145125/discussion-on-question-by-----c--); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если опираться на данные StackOverflow, то данное **утверждение неверно.**

| год | вопросов по С++ | всего вопросов | процент |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 67 | 650 | 10.3076923076923 |
| 2011 | 870 | 22743 | 3.82535285582377 |
| 2012 | 1107 | 34970 | 3.16557048899056 |
| 2013 | 1013 | 30518 | 3.31935251327086 |
| 2014 | 859 | 27303 | 3.14617441306816 |
| 2015 | 1560 | 59092 | 2.63995126243823 |
| 2016 | 3007 | 104091 | 2.88881843771315 |
| 2017 | 3507 | 120279 | 2.91572094879405 |
| 2018 | 4427 | 121774 | 3.6354229966988 |
| 2019 | 3814 | 98487 | 3.87259232182928 |
| 2020 | 4271 | 116901 | 3.653518789403 |
| 2021 | 3320 | 92968 | 3.57112124602014 |
| 2022 | 2915 | 83415 | 3.49457531619013 |
| 2023 | 622 | 21550 | 2.88631090487239 |

Если посмотреть на данные внизу, то можно заметить, что своего пика **абсолютное** количество вопросов по С++ достигло в 2018 году (4427 вопросов), после чего начало снижаться.

И судя по данным текущего года данная тенденция сохранится, т.к. уже прошел квартал, а вопросов всего лишь 622 шт.

**Статистика вопросов с меткой C++, сгруппированных по году создания**
[image: Статистика вопросов по годам]

https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1729427/cpp-by-year#graph

**Статистика вопросов с меткой C++, сгруппированных по году и месяцу создания**
[image: Статистика вопросов по месяцам]

Данные:
https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1729441/cpp-by-month

Запрос, используемый для создания графика:
https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1729443/cpp-by-month-graph#graph

---

Справедливости ради, стоит сравнить все это с графиком общего количества вопросов, заданных на StackOverflow

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1729442/total-count-by-year#graph

И здесь мы можем увидеть, что график статистики запросов по С++, пракически повторяет статистику общего количества запросов на StackOverflow, что говорит о том, что на первый график больше влияет популярность самого StackOverflow, а **относительный интерес к C++ остается стабильным на протяжении всей жизни ресурса**.

---

Ну и как финальный аккорд:
**процент вопросов по C++ относительно общего количества запросов**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1729445/cpp-percents-by-year#graph

Как видно из графика, популярность вопросов по C++ на StackOverflow стабильна и уже на протяжении более чем десяти лет колеблется между 3 и 4 процентами.
(*первый и последний год можно в расчёт не брать, поскольку они неполные*)

Comment: А опираться нужно не только на данные этого сайта.

Comment: @Грузчик У Вас есть какие-то другие данные? Подавляющее число вопросов по `С++` на StackOverflow прилетает как раз таки от студентов из академической среды. И если бы в академической среде значительно увечилась или уменьшилась популярность данного языка, то на данном графике это бы отразилось в первую очередь

Comment: можно еще посмотреть статистику запросов в Яндекс, но там их не получится сгруппировать в один кластер и посмотреть общую статистику